# useRef inside multiple shared components is not returning the ref object

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue that I need to access the refs in a shared `BaseTable` component. For example on a parent route component:

```
function Route() {
  <div>
    <BaseTable />
    <BaseTable />
  </div>
}

function BaseTable() {
  const ref = useRef();

  console.log(ref && ref.current);
  
  return <table ref={ref}>...</table>
}
```

I would expect that upon the render of each `BaseTable` I would see the ref node, however I am only seeing it on one of the children `BaseTable` and the other is only returning null.

Strangely enough (and possibly important), when I make changes to the file and save, the hot reloading then picks up both nodes when re-rendering. When I only have a single `BaseTable` rendering, the ref is set correctly, however this issue only happens when I render multiple `BaseTable` components.

Comment: This should do 
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(ref && ref.current);
}, [])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct.

I think you are confused because your are writing to the `console` in the render function.

The first time the function is rendered, the ref will be `undefined`. Instead, use the `useEffect` hook to write to the console after the component has mounted and the ref has been initialized. You will then see that `ref.current` is the `table` element.

```js
function BaseTable() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref && ref.current);
  }, []);

  return <table ref={ref}>...</table>;
}
```